# Replace NA with last non-NA in data.table by using only data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I want to replace `NA` values with last non-NA values in [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and using [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). I have one solution, but it's considerably slower than `na.locf`:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function(x) {
    x[, X := na.locf(X, na.rm = F)]
    x
}

f2 <- function(x) {
    cond <- !is.na(x[, X])
    x[, X := .SD[, X][1L], by = cumsum(cond)]
    x
}

m1 <- data.table(X = rep(c(NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,6,7,8), 100))
m2 <- data.table(X = rep(c(NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,6,7,8), 100))

microbenchmark(f1(m1), f2(m2), times = 10)

#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr        min          lq      median          uq         max neval
# f1(m1)   2.648938    2.770792    2.959156    3.894635    6.032533    10
# f2(m2) 994.267610 1916.250440 1926.420436 1941.401077 2008.929024    10
```

I want to know, why it's so slow and whether a faster solution exists or not.

Comment: So, what's the reason to avoid `na.locf`? You just don't want to use it?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible. If efficient solution using data.table don't exists then I'll use na.locf.

Comment: For the length of your `m1` vector, using @RomainFrancois `Rcpp` approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24004957/489704) is slightly faster than `zoo::na.locf` for me (0.48 versus 0.63 ms). It's much faster for long vectors, though (e.g. if I repeat your vector 10000 times, I get 1.6 versus 19.6 ms).

Comment: @EldarAgalarov efficient data.table solution is on the way :) https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3341

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a `data.table`-only solution, but it's slightly slower than `na.locf`:

```
m1[, X := X[1], by = cumsum(!is.na(X))]
m1
#       X
#   1: NA
#   2: NA
#   3:  1
#   4:  2
#   5:  2
#  ---   
# 996:  2
# 997:  2
# 998:  6
# 999:  7
#1000:  8
```

Speed test:

```
m1 <- data.table(X = rep(c(NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,6,7,8), 1e6))
f3 = function(x) x[, X := X[1], by = cumsum(!is.na(X))]

system.time(f1(copy(m1)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.84    0.58    4.62 
system.time(f3(copy(m1)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 5.56    0.19    6.04
```

And here's a perverse way of making it faster, but I think one that makes it considerably less readable:

```
f4 = function(x) {
  x[, tmp := cumsum(!is.na(X))]
  setattr(x, "sorted", "tmp") # set the key without any checks
  x[x[!is.na(X)], X := i.X][, tmp := NULL]
}

system.time(f4(copy(m1)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.32    0.51    4.00
```

Comment: Seems with data.table is impossible to make faster replacement than with na.locf. Also need to avoid .SD where is possible.

Comment: @EldarAgalarov added a slightly faster way that I would never use :)

Comment: @EldarAgalarov even more reason not to use complicated and fragile code - I'd honestly stick with `na.locf` even if `f4` is slightly faster on my system, because it's much easier to read and whatever minute gains of speed you get are not going to be worth your time when the code breaks and you don't understand why, because you can't read it

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255200/replace-na-with-last-non-na-in-data-table-by-using-only-data-table#comment37475385_24255200), `Rcpp` is pretty fast for this. Below I compare the `zoo::na.locf` approach, @eddi's `f3` and `f4`, and the `Rcpp` approach posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004957/489704) by @RomainFrancois.

First, the benchmark results:

```
microbenchmark(f.zoo(m1), eddi.f3(m2), eddi.f4(m3), f.Rcpp(m4), times = 10)

## Unit: milliseconds
##         expr      min         lq    median        uq       max neval
##    f.zoo(m1) 1297.969 1403.67418 1443.5441 1527.7644 1597.9724    10
##  eddi.f3(m2) 2982.103 2998.48809 3039.6543 3068.9303 3078.3963    10
##  eddi.f4(m3) 1970.650 2017.55740 2061.6599 2074.1497 2099.8892    10
##   f.Rcpp(m4)   95.411   98.44505  107.6925  119.2838  171.7855    10
```

And the function definitions:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(microbenchmark)
library(Rcpp)

m1 <- m2 <- m3 <- m4 <- 
  data.table(X = rep(c(NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 6, 7, 8), 1e6))

f.zoo <- function(x) {
  x[, X := na.locf(X, na.rm = F)]
  x
}

eddi.f3 = function(x) x[, X := X[1], by = cumsum(!is.na(X))]

eddi.f4 = function(x) {
  x[, tmp := cumsum(!is.na(X))]
  setattr(x, "sorted", "tmp")
  x[x[!is.na(X)], X := i.X][, tmp := NULL]
}

# Make the Cpp function available
cppFunction('
NumericVector naLocfCpp(NumericVector x) {
    double *p=x.begin(), *end = x.end() ;
    double v = *p ; p++ ;

    while( p < end ){
        while( p<end && !NumericVector::is_na(*p) ) p++ ;
        v = *(p-1) ;
        while( p<end && NumericVector::is_na(*p) ) {
            *p = v ;
            p++ ;
        }
    }

    return x;
}')

f.Rcpp <- function(x) {
  naLocfCpp(x$X)
  x
}
```

And all produce identical results:

```
out1 <- f.zoo(m1)
out2 <- eddi.f3(m2)
out3 <- eddi.f4(m3)
out4 <- f.Rcpp(m4)

all(identical(out1, out2), identical(out1, out3), identical(out1, out4))

## TRUE
```

Comment: note that your Rcpp function updates in-place, so shouldn't be used with `:= `, can  be called directly `naLocfCpp(x$X)`

Comment: @jbaums: How to use `f.Rcpp()` for replacing NAs by group? `out4 <- m4[,f.Rcpp(X),by=grp]` does not work...