# Labeling each value in a column by grouping from another column R

Tags: r, data.table

I have an unusual data set that I need to work with and I've created a small scale, reproducible example.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Type = c("A", rep("", 4), "B", rep("", 3), "C", rep("", 5)), Cohort = c(NA,1:4, NA, 5:7, NA, 8:12))
dt <- data.table(Type = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 5)), Cohort = 1:12)
```

I need `DT` to look like `dt` and the actual dataset has 6.8 million rows. I realize it might be a simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out, maybe `setkey`? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace "" by `NA` and use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
DT[Type=="",Type:=NA][,Type:=na.locf(Type)][!is.na(Cohort)]
```

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255200/replace-na-with-last-non-na-in-data-table-by-using-only-data-table if you need to get into `Rcpp` for better performance

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option without using `na.locf`.  Grouped by the cumulative sum of logical vector (`Type!=""`), we select the first 'Type' and the `lead` value of 'Cohort', assign (`:=`) it to the `names` of 'DT' to replace the original column values and use `na.omit` to replace the NA rows.

```
na.omit(DT[, names(DT) :=  .(Type[1L], shift(Cohort, type="lead")), cumsum(Type!="")])
#     Type Cohort
# 1:    A      1
# 2:    A      2
# 3:    A      3
# 4:    A      4
# 5:    B      5
# 6:    B      6
# 7:    B      7
# 8:    C      8
# 9:    C      9
#10:    C     10
#11:    C     11
#12:    C     12
```